# How to fix Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: id, profile_image, status, user, user_id

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication, django-forms

I am a beginner in Django, and I have an academy project. I extended the User model by adding some fields to it and used them in a form to allow users to log in. When I try it, it works, but when I submit the form, I get this error:
Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: id, profile_image, status, user, user_id

I know this question is repetitive, but all the cases I've seen were not similar to mine.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('', 'What is your use of the academy?'),
    ('student', 'Student'),
    ('teacher', 'Teacher'),
    ('author', 'Author'),
)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(null=True, default='profile.jpg')
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
        default='What is your use of the academy?',
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user__username'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import RegisterUserForm

# Create your views here.

def profile(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'common/profile.html'
    )

class RegisterView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from .forms import UserLoginForm
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(authentication_form=UserLoginForm), name='login'),
    path('register/', views.RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

register.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}  

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="card col-md-6 px-0">
                <div class="card-header text-center">
                    <h3 class="mb-0 py-2">{% trans 'Signup' %}</h3>
                </div> 
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% include 'common/form.html' with form=form %}
                        <div class="d-grid gap-2 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
                                {% translate 'Signup' %}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

This is my repo on github:
https://github.com/HamzaWaleedDV/e_academy

I hope for your assistance.

I tried solutions in this proplems:

## [How to Fix: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: description, end_time, id, start_time, title Django Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348013/how-to-fix-cannot-resolve-keyword-user-into-field-choices-are-description?newreg=87668367dbf8463cb160f07f23034932)

[Error: Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074120/error-cannot-resolve-keyword-id-into-field)

[Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: city, id, phone, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994117/cannot-resolve-keyword-username-into-field-choices-are-city-id-phone-etc)

Comment: It makes no sense to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Profile'`, you still use the `User` model, so that is the user model. You either define it correctly, or with an extra model with a one-to-one field.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm sorry, I didn't write `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Profile'`, but I made a mistake and said that I wrote it, then edited it, and deleted it. How do I set it correctly? To the best of my knowledge, this is the correct way to write this model.

Comment: I just tried your github code on my machine and it works fine.  As has already been stated, you *still* have `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Profile'` at the bottom of your **settings.py**.  Remove it.  You are *not* really using a custom `User` model, what you are doing is *extending* the model with a `OneToOneField`.  Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: And I think `USERNAME_FIELD = 'user__username'` is used for the custom user model, which you are not using, so that line must be removed as well, as already stated.

Comment: But how does it work for you? I deleted the line you mentioned, but the account creation process doesn't work.

Comment: My mistake, I only tried the login.  For the registration remove the Meta from the `RegisterUserForm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**
Remove `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Profile'` from **settings.py**.  You are extending the `User` model by creating a `OneToOneField` with your `Profile` model, so you are *still* using the Django `User` model.

---

**Step 2**
Remove `USERNAME_FIELD = 'user__username'` from **models.py**.  Again, this is used for custom user models.

---

**Step 3**
Remove the class Meta from your **models.py**:

```py
# REMOVE THIS
class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = Profile
    fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ("profile_image","status")
```

---

**Step 4**
Adjust your **forms.py** to add the new fields:

```py
class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    
    ...

    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password Confirmation',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs)
    )
    
    # ADD THESE
    # I haven't worked out how to make them pretty, or how to include
    # the choices for the status, but I figure you can do that
    profile_image = forms.ImageField()
    status = forms.CharField(max_length=20)

    field_order = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'profile_image', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'status']
```

---

**Step 5**
Change your `RegisterView` to save the form, and then add a `Profile` since the form you have is just creating a `User`, now you need to create a `Profile` object connected to that `User`:

```py
class RegisterView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()    # The User is now created

        # Create a Profile instance for that User
        Profile.objects.create(user=form.instance, status=self.request.POST.get('status'), profile_image=self.request.FILES['profile_image'])
        super(RegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
        return redirect('login')
```

---

**Finally**
Change your template to SHOW the image:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}

    <style>
        .vertical-line {
            width: 1px; /* عرض الخط بالبكسل */
            height: 100%; /* الارتفاع يمتد ليغطي العنصر بالكامل */
            background-color: #80808081; /* لون الخط */
            margin: 0 10px; /* هامش يمين ويسار للخط */
        }
    </style>
  

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card col-md-12 px-0">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h1 class="text-center">
                        {% trans 'Hello ' %}{{ user.username }}{% trans '' %}
                    </h1>
                </div> 
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
                            <img src="{{ profile.profile_image.url }}" height="200px" width="200px" style="border-radius: 50%;" alt="{{ user.username }}">
                            <h6>
                                <span class="badge bg-info">student</span>
                            </h6>
                            <hr>
                            <h5>{{ user.username }}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 justify-content-start">
                            <div class="vertical-line"></div>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

---

**Result**
After registering a new user, **hyz**:
[image]

---

**Note**
Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model), and be aware that if you *do* end up wanting to use a custom user model (which, the docs themselves actually recommend), it is easy to do at the start of a project, but tricky if you try to do it in the middle of the project.  The same docs tell you how.

---

**-------- EDIT --------**
To allow the user to update the profile image:

**views.py**

```py
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            # user data changed, now change the data in the Profile
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            profile.profile_image = request.FILES['profile_image']
            profile.save()

            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        return render(request, 'common/profile.html', {
            'form': form
        })
```

**forms.py**

```py
class ProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = None

    profile_image = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'profile_image']

        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs=attrs),
        }
    
    # The form saves the User info, now to save the Profile
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['profile_image'].required = False
```

**models.py**

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Added blank=True
    profile_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default='academy_courses/static/profile.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**Make sure to run**

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: thank you, but how i can add image field and charfield to register form?

Comment: Working on it @HamzaWaleed - adding the fields is easy.  You can add those fields like you did the other fields in **forms.py**, i.e., `profile_image = forms.ImageField()`.  The problem I haven't worked out yet is creating the profile when the user registers.

Comment: Okay, I've removed them from the account creation. The problem now is how to add them to the UserChangeForm and store the additional fields with each user.
Sorry for the many questions, I'm still a beginner

Comment: It took me a while since I am not good with class based views, but I think this works, and I hope I've explained why you have to follow these steps.  Best of luck @HamzaWaleed

Comment: thank you very much, final question how i can add profile_image to profileedit form
this is my form
```
class ProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    profile_image = forms.ImageField()
    password = None
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs=attrs),
        }

```
i am sorry for many questions.

Comment: i tried this
class ProfileUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin ,UpdateView):
    form_class = ProfileForm
    model = User
    template_name = 'common/profile.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', args=[self.object.id])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()    # The User is now created
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        # Create a Profile instance for that User
        Profile.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(user=form.instance, profile_image=self.request.FILES['profile_image'])
        super(ProfileUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
not working

Comment: @HamzaWaleed I think the chages I made should allow you to do it.  It worked on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'user__username'
```

Then your forms.py to:

```
class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = Profile
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ("profile_image","status")
```

I must admit that it's kinda confusing how you are doing user registration. Ideally you want to create a User object first then register signal that creates a related profile instance.

Comment: I see this error: `type object 'Profile' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'`

Comment: See comment above. It beats logic to allow users to create their profile instances as in they select themselves from a dropdown? You can use signals to create the profiles once a new user registers then you may redirect them to update their respective profiles.

Comment: I know this; I just put it for testing purposes and will edit it later to solve that problem.

Comment: when i tried: 
Remove this line

USERNAME_FIELD = 'user__username'
Then your forms.py to:

class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = Profile
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ("profile_image","status")

i see this error:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for Profile

Comment: @NickLangat, he shouldn't override the `model` attribute. He will still the username error as his `Profile` model doesn't subclass `AbstractUser` model.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

1. You are not extending the `User` model, you are simply linking it to a `Profile` model with a `OnetoOne` relationship. For your setup it actually makes sense as you don't have fields that need to be on a `User` model. The rule-of-thumb is to let the default User model handle all your authentication and any fields that are simply related to the user be defined on a Profile model as you have rightly done. No point to extend the User model in this case.

If you actually want to extend the `User` model (which, based on your setup, I **strongly** advise you shouldn't), you need to subclass the `AbstractUser` class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    # your extra fields here
```

2. Because you are not actually extending the User model, setting the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Profile'` is meaningless. You are telling Django to use your `Profile` as a model to use for your authentication purposes, but that field doesn't have the `username` and `password` fields that Django expects (that you manually specify in your UserLoginForm) on a `User` model, but you just told it in the `settings` to use the Profile model as authenticating model yet Profile has no `username` or `password` fields. That's why it's throwing that error.

Those are the issues related to the error. But there are some other problems as well.
3. You're subclassing the `AuthenticationForm` form class, and you're overriding username and password fields. That's unnecessary. `AuthenticationForm` renders those fields already. In fact, you shouldn't even subclass it all. You can directly use the `AuthenticationForm` in the url `path` model that's used in the login.
The same problem with the `RegisterUserForm`. All the fields you're specifying are already supplied by the default `User` model that `UserCreationForm` uses. You can simply override the `fields` Meta attribute and add the fields you want to include:

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + (first_name, last_nane, email)
```

Please take a closer and calm look at the [authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) documentation.

Comment: Thank you, I want to add two fields to the account creation process and store them in the database with each user. How can I do this?

Comment: Carefully read the docs link I shared